# Sending Mail automatically to the user who logs in

Tags: c#, email

I'm really bad at this so sorry if I'm asking something obvious but I'm trying to send an automatic mail, every time someone enters their username to access my program, but it gives me an error saying this is not a valid adress. Login_name would be something like john.doe and I want it to be automatically added in front "@mail.com". Is this wrong, do I need another method?

Thanks in advance.

```
mail.To.Add(login_name+"@mail.com");
```

Comment: What is the value of `login_name` exactly? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Like I said, it will be a name and a surname with a "." between. Something like michael.smith, or soner.gonul

Comment: what is "@mail.com"? :)

Comment: It's a company specific e-mail, just changed it to mail.com because it doesn't matter, I have the Stmp settings figured out. If I just use my own e-mail, it sends the mail fine but I can't divide it and add a login_name variable in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    public bool Email(this string body, string subject, string sender, string recipient, string server)
    {
        try
        {
            // To
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.To.Add(recipient);

            // From
            MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(sender);
            mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

            // Subject and Body
            mailMsg.Subject = subject;
            mailMsg.Body = body;

            // Init SmtpClient and send
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(server);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not send mail from: " + sender + " to: " + recipient + " thru smtp server: " + server + "\n\n" + ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Obviously you have to edit here and there but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I will upvote you when I have the necessary reputation. Thanks again.

Comment: I saw that now, and did it:)